# What is the significance of number 3?

Tags: vishnu, shiva

This three is more significant in all religions too. In Vishnu temples - for Brahmans, they give 3 times the tulasi jalam, Shiva has trishool, Nadis - Ida, Pingala, Sushumna, EYES = 3 - Pituitary gland, Pineal gland and Sahasra, Gunas = 3, and even you have body, mind, soul.

Vibuthi = they apply it on forehead with three stripes and same case with thirunamam in Vaishnava. So what's the significance of number 3?

So what is the connection we have with 3? Why they give 3 times the tulasi Jalam in Vishnu temples?

Comment: I don’t think there is any relation or connection. It is just how you observe things. From your another question number 18 has some significance. If you look at 4, you can find couple of observations- 4 vedas, 4 yugas, 4 hands of gods, Brahma has 4 heads. Our scriptures are so huge that you will always find something to correlate :-)

Comment: That's correct but my realisation is there must be something beyond just references.  Because simply we won't have it. For example take 9. It's just not with 9 planets - there are 9 vayus in your body operating according to your Karma. Secondly,  let's take 8. Every deity has 8 gunas and only 8 stages of Bairava avatar Shiva took and they guard 8 directions. And these 8 is related to Ashatama siddhi. So now if we can relate these to path of Moksha, we will get vision for liberation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hinduism, 3 refers to the Early Vedic (Indra, Varun, Agni) as well as the Later Vedic (Bramha, Vishnu, Maheshwara) Trimurty. The 'aum' has three letters- (in Devnagri script) representing Bramha, Vishnu and Maheshwar serially. The gunas inherent in us are three- Rajas, Tamas, and Sattva. In Christianity, 3 refers to the Holy Trinity. It is said that the number 3 is used 523 times in the Bible. In Buddhism, one has Triple Gems, in Taoism there is the Great Triad.

Also, 3 holds significance in the following aspects as well:

1. 3 primary colors
2. 3 lunar phases
3. 3 temporal phases (past, present, future)
4. 3 stages of the Karmic cycle (birth, life, death)

But why is 3 such a powerful number- irrespective of religious and cultural differences- this we do not know. But someday we might.

Comment: You should also cite some sources.